# gitlab-ci: remote shell execution with variable expansion

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Within a gitlab-ci job, I want to create a directory (on a remote server) with the job id and perform some actions more or less as follows:

```
- ssh user@server mkdir -p /user/$CI_JOB_ID
- ssh user@server <perform_some_action_that_creates_several_zip_files>
- LAST_MODIFIED_FILE=$(ssh user@server bash -c 'find /user/$CI_JOB_ID -iname "*.zip" | tail -n 1 | xargs readlink -f')
```

The directory does get created and the action that creates several zips works out.

However, the last command that I use for getting the last modified/created `.zip` does not work, because `$CI_JOB_ID` does not seem to get expanded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `CI_JOB_ID` a environment variable in remote machine?

Comment: no, but this works: `ssh user@server mkdir -p /tmp/$CI_JOB_ID`

Comment: try using double quotation instead : `"find /user/$CI_JOB_ID -iname '*.zip' | tail -n 1 | xargs readlink -f"`. Here, the single quotes may prevent variable expansion for `$CI_JOB_ID`

Comment: I have tried it ... does not work either ... I have also made a local copy of a `variables` file holding entries such as `export CI_JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID`, copying it to the remote server and sourcing it ... no luck either ...

Comment: come to think of it, it makes sense that (when sourcing the `variables` file) the variable is not available... these are distinct `ssh` sessions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is due to your ssh call. The way you do it now, you are mixing contexts :

```
ssh user@server bash -c 'find /user/$CI_JOB_ID -iname "*.zip" | tail -n 1 | xargs readlink -f'
```

- `bash -c 'my_commands'` : you use simple quotes, so ssh will execute **exactly** the instruction `my_commands`. In your case, it will try to find the **remote** value for `$CI_JOB_ID`, instead of using the local one.
- `ssh user@server bash -c "my_commands"` : with`ssh`, the commands to execute on the remote shell are sent as a single string. Thus, if you were to run ssh with this quotation, it would try to run `"bash -c find ... | tail ... | xargs ..."`. Here, only  `find` is run through `bash -c`.

In your case, simply writing directly the following statement should do the trick :

```
ssh user@server "find /user/$CI_JOB_ID -iname '*.zip' | tail -n 1 | xargs readlink -f"
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep using the `bash -c` syntax, you'd have to escape the quotation so that it is propagated to the remote machine :

```
ssh user@server bash -c \"find /user/$CI_JOB_ID -iname '*.zip' | tail -n 1 | xargs readlink -f\"
```